# Visualizing the group operation in higher homotopy groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, visualization

I'm having trouble picturing the homotopy group operation of concatenation between two pointed spaces.

For $n$-spheres, we have for $f,g: S^n \to X$

$$(f * g)(s_1,\ldots, s_n) = \begin{cases}
f(s_1,\ldots, 2s_n)  & \text{for }s_n \le 1/2,\\
g(s_1,\ldots, 2s_n-1) & \text{for }s_n \ge 1/2 
\end{cases}$$

I understand the case with $S^1$, but when $n>1$ above, why is only one coordinate changed and not all the the others? i.e, only $s_n$ has been changed, but all the other coordinates are the same.

Not sure why I'm having trouble viewing this. Thanks.

From *Essential Topology* by Martin Crossley.

Answer (score 3):

I like to think of the concatenation of two sphere maps as first shrinking the equator of the sphere to a point (so we get two spheres wedged together) then mapping the top sphere to $X$ according to $f$ and then mapping the bottom sphere to $X$ according to $g$. Because $f$ and $g$ are base point preserving maps, they agree at the wedge point of the two spheres so this is a well defined process.

This is really just the map you've described, but given in a more geometric way, instead of using symbols.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking of it that way too - but why is only one coordinate changed? I would think that all the coordinates need to be changed...

Comment: The last coordinate changing is like 'running up' the coordinate orthogonal to the equator which you've shrunk to a point at 'double the speed'. Remember the equator of an $n$-sphere is an $(n-1)$-sphere and so the set of points of the form $(x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1},0)$ all lie on the equator (think I got the indices right).

Comment: In other words, the structure comes from the co-H-space structure on $S^n$ given by the "pinch map": $p: S^n \to S^n \vee S^n$. You can interpret your formula as $(f\vee g)\circ p$.